# unique_ptr reset is giving error where auto_ptr reset is working

Tags: c++, c++17

To comply with new c++ standard I am changing my `auto_ptr` to `unique_ptr` however that is causing following issue

```
class A {
static std::unique_ptr<A> ptr; //changed from auto_ptr to unique_ptr
...
}
void A::EndU(...)
{
    ptr.reset();
}
A::~A() {
    Reset(this);
}
void A::Reset(A* inst) {
    fassert(A::ptr.get() == inst, ...); // Assertion Failure
    A::ptr.release();
}
```

`ptr.reset` triggers `~A` which calls `Reset`, but since now its a `unique_ptr` the assertion fails as calling `ptr.get()` inside a `ptr.reset` calls results in returning `0` or `null`. what is the proper way to deal with this issue? should I use a different pointer type if I have to use `ptr.get()` inside ptr.reset or doing this is a bad practice?

Comment: Your setup is strange...

Comment: What is even going on here? Why all of that code was ever needed? As far as I can tell, you should remove `Reset` and `~A` and it should start working.

Comment: A class holding a static owning pointer to an instance of itself? Agreeing with Jarod42. This is beyond strange.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it's an existing code base, was working with auto_ptr, I thought changing to unique_ptr will be a simple conversion.

Comment: Calling `ptr.release()` on an empty `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr` is always safe, so just adjust the `fassert()` all account for `nullptr`, eg: `fassert(A::ptr.get() == inst || A::ptr.get() == nullptr, ...);` Or, just get rid of the `fassert()` altogether: `A::~A() { Reset(); } void A::Reset() { if (A::ptr.get() == this) A::ptr.release(); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau that seems like a workaround but do you think I have a problem with my setup and it is bad code as pointed by the two commenters above?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't know why this code was there in the first place. As far as I can tell, it doesn't make sense for neither `unique_ptr` nor `auto_ptr` to have manual `release` call inside `reset`. I could try to explain why it worked with `auto_ptr` and doesn't work with `unique_ptr`, but I can't tell why anyone thought it's a good idea to write `Reset()` in the first place

Comment: Agreed, it is bad design to begin with. `A::ptr` owns the `A*` pointer to the `A` object, and `ptr` will manage destroying the `A` object and setting the `A*` pointer to `nullptr`, so there is no good reason for the `~A()` destructor to also set the `A*` pointer to `nullptr`. Nobody but `ptr` should be destroying the `A` object, so let it manage the `A*` pointer exclusively.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Take a look at the required order of operations for `std::unique_ptr::reset`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset The state of the unique pointer must be modified to own the new pointer object before attempting to release the old one. The design of the class is bad practice tough: Assume the program exits with `A::ptr` not being empty. Then the destructor of the unique pointer calls `A::~A` which in turn attempts to access the unique pointer object that is in the process of being destroyed. Avoid this kind of logic.